# get dynamic array input in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to get dynamic array input  value in angularjs .i want to collect all values of input in angular js function and retun from function so that the return value can be displayed any where in the page .Is it possible because it is possible in php that if i submit form with array of input like $cat in this case ,and can be displayed anywhere in the page .

```
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat">
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat">
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat">
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller `$scope.cat = ["a","b","c","d"]`
and in your view:

```
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat[0]">
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat[1]">
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat[2]">
<input type="text" name="cat[]" ng-model="cat[3]">
```

or dynamic with ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="c in cat">
  <input type="text" value="{{c}}" ng-model="cat[$index]">
</div>
```

Comment: @ Kreienbring how to collect values u mentioned in or code

Comment: because of the "2-way-data-binding" the array entries will be updated as soon as you type something in the input fields.